# Probability of two people being on the same team

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 12 players that are randomly distributed to 2 teams, so there are 6 players on each team.

**Question 1**: What is the probability of two specific players being on the same team?

Using combinations, the answer is

$$2\times\frac{\binom{10}{4}}{\binom{12}{6}}=\frac{5}{11}\approx45\%$$

because you have 12 players to pick from to fill 6 spots for the first team for the denominator, and 10 players to pick from to fill the 4 remaining spots after fixing player 1 and 2 for the numerator. You multiply by 2 because it could happen for either team.

I would assume the answer is **50%**. Why isn't it?

Suppose there are two teams A and B, and two players 1 and 2. The probability of player 1 being on team A is `1/2`, and the probability of player 2 being on team A is also `1/2`. Thus, the odds of player 1 and 2 being on team A is `1/4` and probability of both of them being on team B is also `1/4`. Adding those two up gives `1/2`. *Thus, there's a 50% chance of both players being on team A or team B.*

**Question 2**: Why isn't the answer exactly 50% when doing it via combinations? Even intuitively, it doesn't make sense why it's not 50%. The odds of two players being on two different teams is ~ 55%?? Why? I don't understand.

Furthermore, as teams get bigger (e.g., 50 players, so 2 teams of 25 players), the odds of 2 players being on the same team becomes 49%. I would assume the odds to stay the same, yet it's approaching 50%. Why?

Comment: "*The odds of*"... First, don't confuse the words 'odds' and 'probability'.  They are related but they convey the information in different ways.  The odds of flipping a heads in a fair coin is $1:1$.  The probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.  Not the same thing.  "*The -probability- of player 1 being on team A is 1/2*"  Yes, that is true.  "*The -probability- of player 2 being on team A is also 1/2*" Also true.  "*Thus the -probability- of player 1 and 2 being on team A is 1/4*"  Wrong.  How did you get that?  $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is not equal to $\Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(B)$ unless they are independent.

Comment: Imagine a much smaller much simpler scenario... you have *only two people* and you will split them into teams of size $1$ each.  Do you really believe that there is a 50% chance that both players will be on the same team?  Even though each team is going to be of size 1???

Comment: In my example with two people, the "*split into teams of size 1 each*" is the key point here, just like in your original problem the "*so there are 6 members on each team*" gives us information on the problem at hand.  This is not the same problem as "*you have 12 people and you flip a coin for each, telling those who flipped heads to go to team A and those who flipped tails to go to team B*".  In that scenario yes you will have your two people go to the same team with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, but you will not necessarily have exactly 6 people per team, or even two nonempty teams at all.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense @JMoravitz. Thanks! How would I calculate the 5/11 using conditional probability like you mentioned in your first comment? Also, I corrected the `odds` and `probability` confusion in my post. And lastly, how do I give you more karma than just upping your comment? This helped me understand probability in general tremendously!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the first question:
Assume the first player has joined one of the two teams at random. Then there are 11 players left, 5 more spots at the first players team and 6 more spots at the other team. The result is that the second player is more likely to be placed in the other team because there are more spots. The first player "blocks" a spot in the first team.